failed to load manifest during ‘anchor build’
I used anchor build command.
E:\Data\on-going\Solana\share-nft>anchor build
[2024-05-17T13:51:20.417937300Z ERROR cargo_build_sbf] Failed to obtain package metadata: cargo metadata exited with an error: error: failed to load manifest for workspace member \\?\E:\Data\on-going\Solana\share-nft\programs\*
referenced by workspace at \\?\E:\Data\on-going\Solana\share-nft\Cargo.toml
Caused by:
  failed to read `\\?\E:\Data\on-going\Solana\share-nft\programs\*\Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (os error 123)


I don’t use Windows, so hard to replicate for me, but does that file exist?
